# set environment variables in java

Tags: java, environment-variables

`I m using jdk7 update 10.

I have already set environment variable as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre\lib"

But `java.lang.NoClassFound` error is still happening and `javac` is also not working.

Why am I getting this error?   the exact error is as folows----

{`Exception in thread"main" java.lang.NoclassFoundError:helloworld/java
       Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:helloworld.java
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run<Unknown Source>
          at java.security.AccessController.doprivileged<Native Method>
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<Unknown Source>
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadclass<Unknown Source>
        could not find the main class: helloworld.java. program will exit`
         }

Comment: Please post the complete noclassdeffound error message

Comment: You don't tell what class it doesn't find, what you try to run etc

Comment: agree with above comments. it's like you posted a question "my computer doesn't work. why?"

Comment: try setting/ appending the Path variable with C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the **JAVA_HOME** as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0" and append to end of the *path* variable as **"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"**

Comment: Tomcat use `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Answer (score 1):

jre refer to java run time environment and you cant compile java codes using it.

Your JAVA_HOME is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\`

And your path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin`